# Используя  SimpleDataSet из базы выбраны данные. Где они, как их присвоить переменным программы?

Tags: delphi-7

Используя  SimpleDataSet из базы выбраны данные. Где они, как их присвоить переменным программы?

Comment: Что значит:

     Как выбрать результаты выборки данных из базы

Вы имеете ввиду SQL-запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну видимо как то так?

```
SimpleDataSet4.DataSet.CommandText := 'needed sql';
```

а дальше какой нибудь Query или Exec ?

Для получения данных надо действовать как то так:

```
memo1.text:= SimpleDataSet1.DataSet.FieldByName('Data').AsString;
```

Я думаю SimpleDataSet1.DataSet ведёт себя как стандартный дельфевый датасет, и чтобы прочитать набор надо делать что то типа:

```
while(not SimpleDataSet1.DataSet.Eof) do
begin
  data := SimpleDataSet1.DataSet.FieldByName('fieldByName').AsYouWish();//AsYouWish ессно не метод
  SimpleDataSet1.DataSet.Next();//тут могу ошибаться но метод содержит next в названии
end;
```

Comment: Меня интересует, как выбрать данные, используя методы компоненты SimleDataSet, для дальней их обработки в приложении Дельфи

Comment: Спасибо за внимание, но возможно я некорректно задаю вопрос.  Я не знаю как присвоить выбранные из базы данные переменным программы после успешного выполнения команды Select, если для выборки данных использовалась компонента SimpleDataSet

Comment: Привет Вам с космостанции с высоты 3340м, Тянь Шань, Алма-Ата. Спасибо за совет. При отсутствии опыта искал FieldByName в SimpleDataSet, а не в DataSet.